# Motorola Xoom XML Manifest

Tags: android, manifest, motorola, xoom

Is there anywhere that I can find a list of the Features that the Xoom has, so that I can update my manifest file accordingly.

Currently the application is not in the Market, and Im not sure what is hindering it.

These are the current Permissions :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Thanks

Comment: If you could post the features you're using, maybe others could point out which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Updated with permissions

Comment: Do you have any uses-feature tags in your manifest?

Comment: Are you using any <uses-feature> tags?

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

Sorry dont know how to make it code in the comment. the 4 spaces doesnt work

Comment: That may be your problem.  It shouldn't block it but it might.  Are you actually using telephony?  If not remove that line and try again.

Comment: i had it without it, and it didnt work either

Comment: Can you post your whole manifest?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to run your application on Android 3.1 then you should set the targetSdkVersion to 12. This may be what's preventing it from showing up in the market. The documentation on targetSdkVersion is not very clear on this, but it's worth a try I suppose. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: targetSdkVersion specifies the level of compatibility behavior your app requests from the system. It does not restrict which devices the app can be installed on.

Comment: My apologies. I had the same problem and it went away after changing the target sdk to 12, but it must have been something else that caused it show up in the Market.
Is it possible that market filtering handles the targetSdk property differently than Android itself? That is, Android won't disallow an application to be installed based on the targetSdk value, but the market will filter it out?

Comment: No. There are many apps still on Market in active use that have not been updated for newer versions of Android that run just fine, specifically because targetSdkVersion tells the device what compatibility behaviors the app was written to expect. You might be thinking of the maxSdkVersion setting, which is used for filtering.